# DB2 SQL : selecting rows where value is different from previous one

Tags: sql, db2

Let's say I have a table (PERSON) like this :
[image: Table Person]

I would like to select only the rows where the value of column "C" has changed from previous row.
In this case, I should get : rows 1, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9 and 15.
I can't figure out how to achieve this.
Does someone has an idea please ?

Thank you

Comment: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/informix-servers/12.10?topic=expressions-lag-lead-functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
WITH PERSON (ROW_NUMBER, C) AS 
(
VALUES
  ( 1, NULL::INT)
, ( 3, NULL::INT)
, ( 4, 189)
, ( 5, NULL::INT)
, ( 6, NULL::INT)
, ( 7, 212)
, ( 8, NULL::INT)
, ( 9, 235)
, (10, 235)
, (11, NULL::INT)
)
SELECT ROW_NUMBER, C
FROM
(
SELECT 
  P.*
, LAG (P.C) OVER (ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER) AS C_PREV
, LAG (P.ROW_NUMBER) OVER (ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER) AS ROW_NUMBER_PREV
FROM PERSON P
)
WHERE 
   ROW_NUMBER_PREV IS NULL 
OR (C IS DISTINCT FROM C_PREV)
```

| ROW_NUMBER | C |
| --- | --- |
| 1 |  |
| 4 | 189 |
| 5 |  |
| 7 | 212 |
| 8 |  |
| 9 | 235 |
| 11 |  |

Comment: Thanks ! It seems to work perfectly fine !

Comment: @AdriL. Great! Please, mark the answer as accepted then.